# How to limit breadcrumb trail to parts after variation level in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, breadcrumb

In my SP2013, I have the structured global navigation showing (breadcrumbs), however its showing too much info, specifically the top levels. Basically my site collection display name is `Root`, then the variation site display name is `en`, then there is a site under `en` called `Work`. When I am on a site `Office` under the `work` site, the breadcrumbs look like

`Root > en > Work > Office`. What can I do so that, I can remove the top levels that's up to and including the variation site. So at all times I want the breadcrumbs to start from the sites under the variation site. So it should look like

`Work > Office`.

And if you are currently on a higher level page, then it should show nothing.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there some SPProviderContent value I need or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set start node for breadcrumb site map, check this article:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemapdatasource.startingnodeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I tried adding `StartingNodeOffsetf="2" ` but it didn't work.

Comment: can you please post snippet here so I can suggest you in better way!